# Extract uint8_t* subset from a vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a `vector<uint8_t>`, and I'm interfacing with an api that expects a `uint8_t* data, size_t size`. I need to provide the api with a subset of my vector, in my current solution I create a subset by using the vector constructor, and then I pass the data() of this new vector to the api:

```
vector<uint8_t> subset(bytes.begin() + offset, bytes.begin() + offset + size);
api(subset.data(), subset.size());
```

This works fine in the majority of cases, but it is running out of memory on constrained devices. Is there a more efficient way to extract a uint8_t* subset from a `vector<uint8_t>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just combine the two but with `data` instead of `begin`.

```
api(bytes.data() + offset, size);
```

Using subscript and address-of operators also works

```
api(&bytes[offset], size);
```

Comment: @Artyer Given the OP's example, `size` is the full size of the byte range being passed to the API, so it should not have `offset` subtracted from it. That would only make sense if `size` were the full size of the `vector` instead.

Comment: @Artyer `size` is the size of the range, offset is added on both sides in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you dont need to make a subset, pass vector's first element and size to want to take out of it. Make sure this size is less than equal to bytes.size()

```
api(&bytes[0],size);
```